# How can I resolve this Blazor Client-Side Local Storage Error: Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: service, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am receiving the following error while trying to run my hot new Blazor app!

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'MyProject.Blazor.Client.ILocalStorageService' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Blazor.Client.AuthService'.
```

Here's my Startup.cs, I think I'm adding the services in the correct order...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

namespace MyProject.Blazor.Client
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();


            // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (begin)
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie();
            // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (end)


        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my AuthService:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyProject.Blazor.Shared.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyProject.Blazor.Client
{
    public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

        public AuthService(HttpClient httpClient,
                           AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider,
                           ILocalStorageService localStorage)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
        }

        public async Task<RegisterResult> Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registerModel, Formatting.Indented);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(json);
            var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/accounts", stringContent);
            var responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            RegisterResult rr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterResult>(responseString);

            return rr ;
        }

        public async Task<LoginResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginModel, Formatting.Indented);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(json);
            var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/Login", stringContent);

            var responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            LoginResult loginresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(responseString);

             if (loginresult.Successful)
            {
                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", loginresult.Token);
                ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginresult.Token);
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", loginresult.Token);

                return loginresult;
            }

            return loginresult;
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("authToken");
            ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsLoggedOut();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my ApiAuthenticationStateProvider:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Blazor.Client
{
    public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        //private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
        private readonly Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
        public ApiAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var savedToken = await  _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            }

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);

            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
        }

        public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string token)
        {
            var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt"));
            var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
        }

        public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
        {
            var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
            var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
            var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
            var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);

            keyValuePairs.TryGetValue(ClaimTypes.Role, out object roles);

            if (roles != null)
            {
                if (roles.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("["))
                {
                    var parsedRoles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(roles.ToString());

                    foreach (var parsedRole in parsedRoles)
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, parsedRole));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles.ToString()));
                }

                keyValuePairs.Remove(ClaimTypes.Role);
            }

            claims.AddRange(keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString())));

            return claims;
        }

        private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
        {
            switch (base64.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
                case 3: base64 += "="; break;
            }
            return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?  I've tried for a day or 2 to figure it out.  I'm not sure if there's some references that are wrong, or what it could be.

Here's my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" Version="5.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\MyProject.Blazor.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the following settings.

### Client.Startup

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
            services.AddScoped<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => 
            provider.GetRequiredService<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>());

        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
```

### **Server.Startup**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
            {
                opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                    new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseResponseCompression();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBlazorDebugging();
            }

            app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
```

What do you need this for ???

```
 // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (begin)
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie();
            // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (end)
```

Don't you use Jwt authentication. See my new settings, and adjust the code to suit you.

Perhaps you should upgrade to the latest versions such as HttpClient, Blazor, etc.

If you still have problems don't hesitate to ask...
If BlazoredLocalStorage gives you some pain, use the Local Storage JavaScript Web Api directly via JSInterop. It's very simple and easy without pain. See MDN for this...5 minutes only...

Hope this helps...